# JS: Access from a property to another property in the same object

Tags: javascript

I'll explain my issue using an example:

I have an object which is called 'ExampleObj' which returns 3 property 'init', 'age', 'weight' and I need to access from age to weight but for some reason i can't do that. Could you explain me why and how can I achieve the correct result?

EDIT: this is the current code, self.tabAnimation() is working on dom ready but... is not working on "click", even if I use (); check the **** in the code, is the line which triggers me error.

```
 return {

init: function() {
  var self = this;
  tabs.init();
  self.tabAnimation();

  tabToggler.on('click', self.tabAnimation );

}, 

tabAnimation: function() {
  var self = this;

  var activeTabBars = function() {
    console.log('lol');
    tabItem.find(bars).each(function() {
      var me = this;
      ****self.animateBars(me,1000)****
    });
  }

  animateOnVisible.init(tabItem, activeTabBars);

},

animateBars : function(el, duration) {
  var percentage = $(el).data('value') + "%";
  $(el).animate({
    'width': percentage
  }, duration);
}
```

}

}

Thank you very much

Davide

Comment: `self.age; // works` No, `self.age; // no-op`.

Comment: `tabToggler.on('click', self.tabAnimation );` is your problem. The function is not bound to `self`.

Comment: it's something weird, when I trigger the click it returns me "lol" (the console log) but not the function called after the CL) .. but on DOM ready it triggers correctly the function self.animateBars(me,1000)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `this`:

```
age: function() {
  console.log('some random log');
  var me = this;
  me.weight;
  me.weight(something);
},
```

You don't have to assign `this` to another variable, but it doesn't hurt anything if you do.

Note that in your "init" function,

```
  self.age;
```

by itself will do nothing. To call the function, you have to write it

```
  self.age();
```

Comment: Whoa, OP completely edited his question…

Comment: @Bergi it's so weird when that happens.

Comment: @Bergi I'm sry, I just updated the sample code with the current code ... having the same issue :(